# True bool returns False

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

I am making a Discord bot which uses SQLite to save data in a database (just for context, no relevance to the question) and in the function that levels a user up, it will return `True` if the user had enough XP to level up at least once. The bool works as intended in the function (before I return the bool, it is `True`) but as soon as I return it, it is set to `False`.

```
def addMessage(message):
    "Adds a message to a member's data"
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT lastmessage FROM tbluser WHERE userid = {message.author.id}")

    if message.channel.slowmode_delay > 0: # If there is slowmode on the channel that the message was sent on
        addHoliness(message.author, limit(rac.messageValue * message.channel.slowmode_delay, 75))
    
    else: # If there is no slowmode on the channel that the message is from
        addHoliness(message.author, rac.messageValue)
    
    levelledUp = checkLevel(message.author)
    
    if levelledUp: # If the user has levelled up devotion
        embed = discord.Embed(colour = getColour(message.author), title = "Devotion Level {getAttribute(message.author, 'devotion')}", description = "You have levelled up your devotion from interacting with **{message.guild.name}**'s {message.channel.mention} text channel.")
        
        await message.guild.system_channel.send(embed = embed)


def checkLevel(member):
    "Checks for devotion level ups, grants them to the member, and then returns a bool indicating if the member has levelled up devotion or not"
    devotion = getAttribute(member, "devotion")
    holiness = getAttribute(member, "holiness")
    nextDevotion = getAttribute(member, "nextdevotion")
    change = False
    
    while holiness >= nextDevotion: # While the member has enough holiness to level up their devotion
    
        if not change: # Changes the change variable to True if it is False
            change = True
        
        devotion += 1
        holiness -= nextDevotion
        nextDevotion = limit(75 * (devotion - 1) + 200, 5000)
    
    setAttribute(member, "devotion", devotion)
    setAttribute(member, "holiness", holiness)
    setAttribute(member, "nextdevotion", nextDevotion)
    connection.commit()
    
    return change
```

More specifically: the variable `change` in the `checkLevel` function is `True`. The variable `levelledUp` in the `addMessage` function is `False` even though it is meant to be the returned value of `change` in the `checkLevel` function.

EDIT #1:
I have also just found out that the value that `checkLevel` is returning is actually not `True`. When I print it on the line before `return change`, it prints `True False` on seperate lines. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: You should debug your code (i.e. set breakpoints, step, inspect...). Probably your functions are called more than once. But with what you have provided it is impossible to say what is happening.

Comment: @trincot Literally with the little you told me, I was able to find the problem. *"Probably your functions are called more than once"* Yeah, they were. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to [Trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) for his help not only in this issue but in another one I had a few years before this one.

He said the following: *"You should debug your code (i.e. set breakpoints, step, inspect...). Probably your functions are called more than once. But with what you have provided it is impossible to say what is happening."*

Which got me thinking that if I called the function more than once, it'd definitely break. So, I hit `Ctrl + F` and looked for `checkLevel` and what do you know, I used the function in another function, causing the return value to be simultenously `True` and `False` somehow.